# Compilation error using asm!("mov...") on aarch64

Tags: rust, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm running a [code sample from a book](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Asynchronous-Programming-in-Rust/blob/main/ch01/a-assembly-dereference/src/main.rs) on a Mac/aarch64, and getting a compilation error.

```rust
fn dereference(ptr: *const usize) -> usize {
    let mut res: usize;
    unsafe { 
        asm!("mov {0}, [{1}]", out(reg) res, in(reg) ptr)
    };
    res
}
```

I get:

```
error: expected compatible register or logical immediate
  --> src/main.rs:20:15
   |
20 |         asm!("mov {0}, [{1}]", out(reg) res, in(reg) ptr)
   |               ^
   |
note: instantiated into assembly here
  --> <inline asm>:1:10
   |
1  |     mov x8, [x0]
   |             ^
```

Having searched for the error message, I believe the architecture has something to do with it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it yet. I'm looking at the Rust [inline assembly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html) doc, but as the topic is completely new to me, I can't map my example that is failing to compile to what I'm seeing in the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov x8, [x0]` looks like x86-64 syntax with AArch64 register names.  (From your answer, it looks like you just found an example that maybe failed to mention it was for x86-64, and tried compiling it for AArch64.)

AArch64 is a load/store architecture: special instructions (like `ldr` and `str`) are the only one that access memory, e.g. `ldr x8, [x0]`. Look at compiler output for a Rust function that derefs a pointer, e.g. [Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:8),source:%27//+As+of+Rust+1.75,+small+functions+are+automatically%0A//+marked+as+%60%23%5Binline%5D%60+so+they+will+not+show+up+in%0A//+the+output+when+compiling+with+optimisations.+Use%0A//+%60%23%5Bno_mangle%5D%60+or+%60%23%5Binline(never)%5D%60+to+work+around%0A//+this+issue.%0A//+See+https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/5939%0A%23%5Bno_mangle%5D%0Apub+fn+dereference(ptr:+*const+usize)+-%3E+usize+%7B%0A++++unsafe%7B%0A++++++++*ptr%0A++++%7D%0A%0A//++++let+mut+res:+usize%3B%0A//++++unsafe+%7B+%0A//++++++++asm!!(%22ldr+%7B0%7D,+%5B%7B1%7D%5D%22,+out(reg)+res,+in(reg)+ptr)%0A//++++%7D%3B%0A//++++res%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bno_mangle%5D%0Apub+fn+deref_no_unsafe(reference:+%26usize)+-%3E+usize+%7B%0A++++*reference%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.00989918782997,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1760,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-C+opt-level%3D3%27,overrides:!((name:edition,value:%272021%27),(name:arch,value:aarch64-apple-darwin)),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.76.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50.990100812170056,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) shows a pure-Rust dereference compiling for aarch64-apple-darwin to `ldr x0, [x0]` and `ret`.

By contrast, x86-64 uses `mov` for loads, stores, and register copies: most x86-64 instructions that read and write registers are also available with a memory source or destination.  (This is one of the CISC vs. RISC differences in the designs of the two architectures.)

---

Read a tutorial on AArch64 asm, e.g. https://modexp.wordpress.com/2018/10/30/arm64-assembly looks reasonable; google found it when I searched for `inline assembly x86-64 aarch64 ldr`. It has a short section comparing x86 vs. AArch64 assembly, but that's just a table of some equivalents for reg, reg instructions.  The AArch64 equivalent for `movzx eax, byte [rdi]` is `ldrb w0, [x0]`, vs. `movzx eax, dil` being `uxtb w0, w0`, again with special instructions for zero-extending or sign-extending narrow loads.

Really they're quite different architectures. The way a lot of things are done is quite different, e.g. instructions don't set FLAGS by default, you need an S suffix on the mnemonic. (Except for `cmp` and `tst` which exist only to write flags.)  And instead of push/pop, there's `stp` / `ldp` with post-increment addressing.  (Always done as a pair of 64-bit regs to keep the stack aligned by 16.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after spending a bunch of time but not until I posted this question, I found the answer.

The template in `Arm64` assembly should be `"ldr {0}, [{1}]"`, not `"mov {0}, [{1}]"`.

What helped:

1. I decided to start from the beginning and read the [Rust By Example chapter on inline assembly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rust-by-example/unsafe/asm.html). I found that the simplest `add` example also didn't compile for me.
2. After googling `add` on `Arm64`, I came across [the assembly cheat sheet](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Ekwebb/cs31/resources/ARM64_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) which showed that the syntax for `add` was simply different on this architecture from `x86/x86-64` (3 arguments rather than 2).
3. I stared more carefully at the syntax for the `mov` instruction and saw the issue. Then the author pointed out `ldr` was the correct instruction on aarch64.

Comment: `mov {0}, {1}` would return the pointer, not dereference it.